# Set GradientDrawable Color in Adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I got the color from the button background and store as a String in the database. Later I want to use this color String in my recyclerView adapter to set the color of my TextView. Below is my code:

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NoteListAdapter.NoteListHolder holder, int position) {
    current = data.get(position);
    final String text = current.getText();
    final String get_tag_text = current.getTag();
    final String get_tag_color = current.getTag_color();

    int[] colors = {Color.parseColor(get_tag_color)};
    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, colors);

    holder.note_text.setText(text);
    holder.tv_tag_text.setBackground(gd);
    holder.tv_tag_text.setText(get_tag_text);
}
```

The error I got is "**Unknown color**". The saved color format in the database is (The saved color format is `android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable@d1790a4`)

Below is the code to get the color from a button background drawable file and also my button xml code

```
 color  = (GradientDrawable) tag_watchlist.getBackground().mutate();
tag_color= color.toString();

 <Button
        android:id="@+id/tag_watch"
        style="@style/tag_buttons"
        android:background="@drawable/watchlist_button"
        android:text="Watchlist" />
```

drawable file code for the button background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"
android:padding="10dp">
<solid android:color="#a40ce1"/>
<corners android:radius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue??

Comment: What value are you getting in `final String get_tag_color = current.getTag_color();` line

Comment: android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable@d1790a4

Comment: Share your Model class a.k.a Setter Getter class please

Comment: both getter and setter are String data type

Comment: look at the updated answer, also share the **tag_watchlist**

Comment: it's not working. can we use split function or any other to get only the required string value.

Comment: please share **watchlist_button**

Comment: I already share its xml file. The purpose of the button is when someone clicked the button, button's text and color store in a variable that is later used to set the color and text of the textView widget.

Comment: I meant to **watchlist_button drawable** which is used for the button background

Comment: I have updated my code again

Comment: @AsmaAhmad look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Edited answer*

You are getting exception `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown color` mean that you are not passing the color in supported formats to method `Color.parseColor`.

Make sure you pass the values in following format

```
#RRGGBB
#AARRGGBB
```

Here is the valid example

```
Color.parseColor("#FF4081")
```

For more information look at documentation [Color.parseColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color#parseColor(java.lang.String))

As per your requirement, you can achieve this API level 24 onward. If you are using current **minSdkVersion 24**, try below

Change your model class to save color as `Integer` instead `String`.

```
GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable) tag_watchlist.getBackground().mutate();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    int color = gradientDrawable.getColor().getDefaultColor();
    Log.d("TAG","Color is :"+color);
    current.setTagColor(color); // where current is your model class
}
```

To get the color back from model

```
int color = current.getTagColor();
```

Comment: The problem is the saved color is the string of Gradient Drawable

Comment: @AsmaAhmad share your **current** model class please, also share the logic where you saving color in your model class

Comment: android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable@d1790a4

Comment: this is **android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable@d1790a4** not the valid color for sure. Share the code where you saving the color so that we can fix.

Comment: from this method the return color value is zero

Comment: make sure you have set minSdkVersion  as 24 in your build.gradle, I have verified for me it works. Also add log after this line to print the color value `int color = gradientDrawable.getColor().getDefaultColor();` have added the same in answer post as well

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide at least two colors for the `GradientDrawable` the `startColor` and the `endColor`

It will probably throw an exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: needs >= 2 number of colors` with this code:

```
int[] colors = {Color.parseColor(get_tag_color)};
    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, colors);
```

Change your code with this:

```
int[] colors = {Color.parseColor(start_color), Color.parseColor(end_color)};
        GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, colors);
```

If you have `get_tag_color` for both of your `startColor` and `endColor` then replace accordingly but that won't be helpful with `GradientDrawable`.

Comment: The problem is the saved color is the string of Gradient Drawable. How to convert this string into Color

Comment: Can you please share what are you getting from `current.getTag_color();`

Comment: android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable@d1790a4

Comment: You need to actually get the color from your XML which should be in proper `hexcode` or `int`